Markov Chains with Changing Number of States
I have seen these kinds of Discrete State Markov Chains before (Continuous Time or Discrete Time):

Homogeneous (Probability Transition Matrix is constant)
Non-Homogeneous (Probability Transition Matrix changing with time )

But what about the following type of Markov Chain where the number of states change with time:

Suppose the markov chain Xt initially starts with S = 0,1,2...k states
There is some random variable Tau that follows some distribution P(tau).
Next we have a probability distribution of S, i.e. P( |S|_t+1 = k2 given |S|_t-1 = k2 AND Tau=t)... this is the probability that the state space of Xt has k2 states at time t+1 given there were k1 states at time t AND some random amount of time Tau has passed (k has to be positive integers)
Finally, write: P(Xt+1 = j  given Xt = i, |S|_t =k1, Tau = t)
I suppose some constraints can be added that bound the number of states between a < |S| < b ... and I can also add something to say that the total number of states always increases with time or always decreases with time, e.g. |S|_t+1 >= |S|_t for all t>=0 . Or P(|S|_t+1 gtiven |S|_t) could be something like a simple Random Walk which prevents the total number of states growing or shrinking too quickly (i.e. max growth/reduction of 1 at each time)
I might also need some "probability allocation function" that re-allocates probabilities when the number of states shrinks or grows. For example, no matter the size of |S_t, all elements in the corresponding transition matrix are always equal to each other

Is this type of Markov Chain ever analyzed in practice? I think this kind of resembles a doubly stochastic process (e.g. Cox Process - a Poisson Process where the rate parameter evolves according to a Gaussian Process)?
I suppose this process I described in my question no longer follows the memoryless property. I was thinking that maybe in some real world examples (e.g. queues), the number of servers might change conditional on the current conditions and history of the queue (e.g. as employees start to quit, the remaining employees become more overworked and now start to quit at higher rates, further influencing the remaining employees to quit, etc.)
Is this problem ever analyzed?

Maybe have a look at Reversible Jump MCMC, where the state space (typically the parameter space of a Bayesian model) changes during simulation.

The number of states change, but can we consider the set of states as being embedded in the same larger set? E.g a discrete random walk on a latice, that can be regarded as a growing space, but one can also consider the entire space from the start.


I suppose this process I described in my question no longer follows the memoryless property.

The memoryless property means that the transition to the next state is independent from the past, conditional on the current state.
Sure, the current state depends on the past...
... but it doesn't matter how we got to the current state, the past has only an effect via the current state.
In order to determine the next state it is sufficient to know the current state, and we don't need to know about the past of the current state.

I was thinking that maybe in some real world examples (e.g. queues), the number of servers might change conditional on the current conditions and history of the queue (e.g. as employees start to quit, the remaining employees become more overworked and now start to quit at higher rates, further influencing the remaining employees to quit, etc.)

In this example one could just define the state as the potential number of employees. The state space isn't really changing in size. You could define it from the start as all non-negative integers.
If, alternatively, you consider concrete states like "Bob, Sue, Steve and Bill are employee", "Bob Sue and Steve are employee", etc. then the state space might change in time as people get "eliminated" or "created". But for most purposes people just consider states like "4 people are employee", "3 people are employee", etc.

This is essentially just a regular Markov chain (under some simplifying assumptions)
At present your question is a little ill-posed, since you appear to conflate the value of the exogenous variable $\tau$ with the time index in some places, and you also assert an unclear relationship between these things in other places.  As a simplifying assumption, I'm going to assume that you intend for $\tau$ to be an exogenous variable without any relationship to the time index.  (If that is not what was intended, you may need to be clearer in your model.)
You mention in your question that you are willing to assume that the set of possible states is bounded, so let's use that simplifying assumption.  Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the set of allowable values of $\tau$, let $\mathscr{S}(\tau) \subseteq \mathbb{N}_+$ denote the set of allowable states under the exogenous variable $\tau$, and let $\mathscr{S} \equiv \cup_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}} \mathscr{S}(\tau) \subseteq \mathbb{N}_+$ denote the overall set of possible states.  The main thing that is left unspecified in your model is how the transition probabilities for the allowable states change depending on $\tau$.  That can be encapsulated by defining the conditional transition probability function:
$$H(i,j|\tau) \equiv
\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = j | X_t=i, \tau = t),$$
and noting that this function must obey the requirement $H(i,j|\tau) = 0$ for all $j \neq \mathscr{S}(\tau)$ (i.e., it does not allow transition into a state that is precluded by the pressent value of $\tau$).  Once you have defined this function, assuming that the random variable $\tau$ is independent of the state of the Markov chain (which appears to be your intention) we can apply the law of total probability to get the following form for the marginal transition probabilities:
$$\begin{align}
p_{i,j} 
&= \mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = j | X_t=i) \\[12pt]
&= \sum_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}} \mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = j | X_t=i, \tau = t) \cdot p_\tau(t) \ dt \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}} H(i,j|t) \cdot p_\tau(t) \ dt. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Determination of these marginal transition probabilities for all $i,j, \in \mathscr{S}$ gives you the entire (marginal) transition probability matrix over the full space $\mathscr{S}$, which then tells you the marginal behaviour of the chain $\{ X_t | t \in \mathbb{N} \}$.
